# Time it takes to open a new terminal window

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, real-time, kitty

I just checked my timings: it takes about 0.41-0.45 seconds to open a new `gnome-terminal` window and about 0.55-0.65 seconds to open `kitty`. And it does bother me a bit that it takes so much time to open (I want it to be close to instant, like UI elements are responding to mouse/keyboard events). I want some suggestions for either speeding up window open process or some terminal alternatives that open faster (I use `kitty` for several years now). Maybe someone can share their timings, so I can compare mine to something (I didn't find anything about this issue on the Internet).

Here's a MWE:

```bash
terminal=kitty # gnome-terminal
date +%s.%N > .start; $terminal -- sh -c 'echo "$(date +%s.%N)-$(cat .start)" | bc | cut -c 2- > .diff; rm -f .start'; cat .diff; rm -f .diff
```

My config: Laptop with i7-8550U, SSD, Ubuntu 20.04.

P.S. I'm hoping soon to hop to Pop!_OS 22.04. After that, I'll check my timings again (perhaps they'll improve).

---

**Update**:

Tried with zero config using root:

- `kitty`: 0.38-0.43 seconds
- `gnome-terminal`: 0.41-0.46 seconds

---

**Update 2**:

Run `ranger` using `kitty` with root (0 conf.) and `alacritty` (cargo crate is user-wide; 0 conf.):

- `kitty`: 0.50-0.57 seconds
- `alacritty`: 0.37-0.43 seconds
- `alacritty` without `ranger`: 0.22-0.28 seconds (*now we're talking*)

`kitty`:

```bash
date +%s.%N > .start; kitty ranger --cmd 'shell echo "$(date +%%s.%N)-$(cat .start)" | bc | cut -c 2- > .diff; rm -f .start; kill $PPID'; cat .diff; rm -f .diff
```

`alacritty`:

```bash
date +%s.%N > .start; alacritty -e ranger --cmd 'shell echo "$(date +%%s.%N)-$(cat .start)" | bc | cut -c 2- > .diff; rm -f .start; kill $PPID'; cat .diff; rm -f .diff
```

P.S. I use [`ranger`](https://github.com/ranger/ranger) a lot (want to switch to [`lf`](https://github.com/gokcehan/lf)) and 99% I open it with a shortcut bound to `kitty ranger` command.

Comment: gnome-terminal has a daemon that holds most of the state ready, and a new window needs to do little more than draw a window decoration and allocate a PTTY; it needs to load 0 libraries that aren't already loaded. So that might be advantageous here.

Comment: out of interest: how does one measure something like that?

Comment: try alacritty it might take less time to open

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I printed `date +%s.%N` to file and then opened subterminal which calculated time difference. Then (just 'cuz why not) it printed time difference to the other file and finally the main terminal printed the content of the last modified file (time difference). Here, I'll write a MWE.

Comment: @Andrew15_5 ah, thanks! Yeah, cute :) I get roughly 0.13s on my machine with alacritty; I will have to say that it's possible alacritty never actually *shows* anything within that time - the execution of a command and the displaying of its output are things that can happen separately!

Comment: @Andrew15_5 My method to measure the same: `/usr/bin/time -f "%e" $terminal -- true`

Comment: @Andrew15_5 my even *more* detailed method to measure this (on Linux): 1. install the `perf` command (for you, `sudo apt install linux-tools-common`), 2. enable stalking what processes do for normal users for this session: `sudo sysctl -w kernel.perf_event_paranoid=-1`, 3. Run an alacritty and record in short time intervals where it's "stuck" on all CPUs: `perf record -a alacritty -e true`, 4. analyze the result: `perf report`.

Comment: This shows that indeed, alacritty uses about half of that time (the other half are mostly… idling, I guess waiting for hardware to fulfill requests), which itself is relatively evenly split between functions handling fonts, and talking to Xorg, and talking to the nvidia driver.

Comment: xfce4-terminal here opens in less than 0.05 seconds.

Comment: Let's mention one more way of opening the terminal which hasn't been mentioned yet. If you have a `gnome-terminal` window on the front (i.e. having the keyboard focus), the hotkey Ctrl+Shift+N asks that window directly to open a new one (no new terminal process to launch, I believe no dbus communication to take place etc.), so is probably noticeably faster than other ways of opening gnome-terminal. If the source window has a profile with ranger/lf as custom command, so will the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that only `kitty` (among those who I tested) can support ligatures. And looking at how it improves, I don't think anything can substitute it for me. And after some research, I found that (probably on a lot more speedy PC) some people manage to open `kitty` in 0.2s (0.1s to load OpenGL and 0.1s for the rest). Also, I fortunately found that kitty does support "server-client" architecture. You can create any number of groups in which terminals share some stuff (I don't have any specifics). And to create "the main" (the easiest) group, I only had to add 3 more chars: `kitty -1`:

> --single-instance, -1
> If specified only a single instance of kitty will run. New invocations
> will instead create a new top-level window in the existing kitty
> instance. This allows kitty to share a single sprite cache on the GPU
> and also reduces startup time. You can also have separate groups of
> kitty instances by using the --instance-group option.

Now the terminal (fully customized) opens in less than 0.2s (0.16-0.18)! That's 0.4s or 3.3 times faster than my first timings. It's about as fast as other server terminals (`gnome-terminal`, `xfce4-terminal`). There are only 2 downsides:

- I don't think there's a way to run server in background, therefore 1st terminal opens with regular speed (0.57s);
- If you kill one terminal (maybe something did freeze) — the other ones all go with it.
  But currently I think these things aren't an issue for me and I probably can live with them. I installed Pop!_OS 22.04 and the UI is super responsive (I really think it will decrease the time even further).